# Does Excel 365 Not Let you Drag the Formula Bar Down?

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

Am I crazy or can you not drag down the formula bar in Excel 365?

**Clarification:**

In the formula bar at the top of the screen, where you enter in your formulas (i.e. A1 + A2), is there a way to make this box bigger?

[image]

Comment: You can make the bar bigger (two rows) . Is that what you mean?  Not exactly clear above.

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: Yes, you can make the formula bar larger. Answer provided.

Comment: Are you using office 365? I can't seem to do it. Can you post, as the answer, how you are doing it and confirm you are using office 365?

Comment: You will need to use the Desktop version.

Comment: Seems to be that way :/

Comment: Thanks anyway, 'preciate it